# I get a blank page after deployment to github without any error

Tags: reactjs, github, web-deployment

I built something from react for the first time, and I'm about to deploy it on my github.

But when I go to my repository from github, it displays a blank page(But I'm not sure if the part of css is working as I can see black background color on it)

Since it doesn't show any error on the console, it was hard for me to figure out what the problem is.

I'd be great if someone can help me out on this.

https://stone-skipper.github.io/svs/#/

This is the link I'm trying to deploy on.

### - Some people mentioned the problems from BrowserRouter, so I tried HashRouter, but it also didn't work.

```
// App.js
import React from "react"
import { Sev, Contents } from "./screens"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Sev} />
      <Route path="/contents" component={Contents} />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
//package.json
{
  "homepage": "http://stone-skipper.github.io/svs/",
  "name": "sev-exhib",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modali": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-cursor-position": "^3.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

```
//index.js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import "./index.css"
import App from "./App"
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker"

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))


serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Comment: I am running apps using `react-router-dom` on GH Pages just fine -- would you happen to have the source code in a repo? It would be a lot easier to help troubleshoot that way.

Comment: Hi @MattOestreich, and yes all the source code are in the repo. https://github.com/stone-skipper/svs I'd really appreciate if you can take a look!

Comment: So, that is all of the built code - basically, your source code is "compiled" into that. Is the master branch private or something?